# which elements are affected by the line-height property?

Tags: css, xhtml

which elements are affected by the line-height property?

Comment: I'm sorry, but this question is incomprehensible. Are you asking about which elements are affected by the `line-height` property?

Comment: @Yi Jiang - yes. I changed the question

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_line-height.asp

Comment: line-height is inherited so all children of an element will inherit the line-height of their parent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It affects all of them according to the [W3 line-height spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height).  It's behavior is different depending on the type of element it is applied to:

**block-level, table-cell, table-caption or inline-block**

> [on one of the above] whose content is composed of
>   inline-level elements, 'line-height'
>   specifies the minimal height of line
>   boxes within the element.

**inline-level**

> ...specifies the height
>   that is used in the calculation of the
>   line box height (except for inline
>   replaced elements, where the height of
>   the box is given by the 'height'
>   property).

Line box height is then defined as:

> the distance between the uppermost box top and the lowermost box bottom.

Comment: I still don't understand what's your meaning.If a block-level element is composed of inline-level elements, then the height of the blokc-level element is affected by the line-height of the inline-level elements. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It applies to [all](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) HTML elements, but has different behaviour depending on the element.

From the [CSS spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS1/):

> All elements have a 'line-height'
>   property that, in principle, gives the
>   total height of a line of text.

Comment: Ok and does all browser have different line height? should i keep `line-height:0` in css reset?

Comment: No it's not in Eric meyer reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/05/01/reset-reloaded/ he is using `body {line-height: 1;}`

Comment: Don't set line-height to 0. Either leave it at 1, 100% or line-height:normal;

Answer (score 0):

Applies to all elements, with different behaviour of course:

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height

> On a block-level, table-cell,
>   table-caption or inline-block element
>   whose content is composed of
>   inline-level elements, 'line-height'
>   specifies the minimal height of line
>   boxes within the element. The minimum
>   height consists of a minimum height
>   above the block's baseline and a
>   minimum depth below it, exactly as if
>   each line box starts with a zero-width
>   inline box with the block's font and
>   line height properties (what TEX calls
>   a "strut").
>
> On an inline-level element,
>   'line-height' specifies the height
>   that is used in the calculation of the
>   line box height (except for inline
>   replaced elements, where the height of
>   the box is given by the 'height'
>   property).